# jQuery-UI Date and Time-Range Picker

Tags: jquery-ui, range, datetimepicker

I'm creating a page to manage the our times at the office (for example when we made home-office). This requires selecting a date and then time-range.

I know about the Date-Picker from jQuery-UI, and there also seems to be something interesting for time picking. But since I need a start and end time, a UI to select date and time range would be perfect. Is there something you could recommend?

Comment: If you consider a paid plugin I would recommend mine: https://codecanyon.net/item/calentim-date-time-range-picker/20099228

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visit [jQuery UI datepicker range example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) and click "view source".

Combine with jquery timepicking solution [found here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

That should hopefully get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Another interesting option could be handle the date in the date-picker and the time-range with a separated UI component (in this specific case **start** and **end** time are in the same day).

You can take a look at these time-range sliders:

```
$("#slider-range").slider(options_object);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrweinb/MQ6VT/

http://marcneuwirth.com/blog/2010/02/21/using-a-jquery-ui-slider-to-select-a-time-range/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
      timepicker: true,
      allowTimes: [
          '12:00', '12:30', '13:00','13:30','14:00',
'14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00',   ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.16/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.16/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can select  time using this slider.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 23px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 0;
    background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/contrasticon.png');
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 23px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 0;
    background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/contrasticon.png');
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="10" max="22" maxvalue="10" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo">4PM</span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
slider.oninput = function() {
    var time=slider.value;
    if(time<12){
    time=time+'AM';
    }
    else if(time>12){
    time=time-12+'PM';
    }
    else if(time=12){
    time=12+'PM';
    }
    //alert(time);
  output.innerHTML = time;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```