# jquery datetimepicker optional range hour

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

how to implements optional hour range in jquery datetimepicker from 9am - 9pm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13769913/

Comment: i need datetimepicker not datepicker ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this plugin: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ 
And apply the restriction like:

```
$('#rest_example_1').timepicker({
    hourMin: 8,
    hourMax: 16,
    //Other options here
});
```