# Can i use date picker rang for time range picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have found date rang but i haven't found `time range picker` anyone know about it?

[datepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker)

- can i use this one for time rang picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-header" style="width: 600px;">

            <label for="start">Start time:</label>
            <input id="start" value="8:00 AM" />

            <label for="end" style="margin-left:3em">End time:</label>
            <input id="end" value="8:30 AM"/>

        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function startChange() {
                    var startTime = start.value();

                    if (startTime) {
                        startTime = new Date(startTime);

                        end.max(startTime);

                        startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() + this.options.interval);

                        end.min(startTime);
                        end.value(startTime);
                    }
                }

                //init start timepicker
                var start = $("#start").kendoTimePicker({
                    change: startChange
                }).data("kendoTimePicker");

                //init end timepicker
                var end = $("#end").kendoTimePicker().data("kendoTimePicker");

                //define min/max range
                start.min("8:00 AM");
                start.max("6:00 PM");

                //define min/max range
                end.min("8:00 AM");
                end.max("7:30 AM");
            });
        </script>

        <style scoped>
            #example .k-timepicker {
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            #example h3 {
                clear: both;
            }

            #example .code-sample {
                width: 60%;
                float:left;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            #example .output {
                width: 24%;
                margin-left: 4%;
                float:left;
            }

        </style>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also read the following article:

[TimePicker / Range selection](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/timepicker/rangeselection)

Comment: this is fine brother i can build this but this is my second choice i need any plugin like bootstrap datetime picker.

Comment: Bootstrap provide datetime picker plugin.use jquery/js to customize it.

Comment: Ok thanks i will customize bootstrap plugin thanks for giving me idea.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery-UI Date and Time-Range Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769764/jquery-ui-date-and-time-range-picker)

from the answers of above thread i found a very good solution.. It was pretty awesome. and very easy with rich UI Experience than Telric controls.
Here the solution is achieved with Using the jquery slider as a time range picker. I loved this solution.

But if i could use it with mouse wheel that would excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap time picker.please use this

[bootstrap Time Picker](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/timepicker/)