# how to display dropdown in different section using arrows in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a dropdown like this

```html
  <select name="time" style="width:174px; height:27px;">
  <option value="6">6am</option>
  <option value="6">7am</option>
  <option value="8">8am</option>
  <option value="9">9am</option>
</select>
```

if the values I want to insert are more, then can I change it into 2 sections with arrows to move between sections, as we see in dropdown calander.
just like below image
[image]

can anyone help

Comment: NOt sure what are you trying to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: @AyushKumar updated the question

Comment: are you trying to implement datepicker?

Comment: @AyushKumar i dont wnt date, i want to add some values in dropdown, if the values are more, i want to split the values in 2 sections, so when the user clicks the arrow , user can switch btw sections

Comment: @are you looking for time range than refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769764/jquery-ui-date-and-time-range-picker and this https://codepen.io/fikrimarhan/pen/Pmaooq

Comment: Just Rephrasing, You want the select dropdown to split into a 2 dimensional table like structure if the data is more than a certain value and the user can choose to view it as a long single list or a 2-D list. Right?

Comment: @AyushKumar yes

Comment: You would probably need to search for plugins to achieve this functionality. Can't do it with simple css/js

Comment: @Anil thanks it helped